# Model in Payload not recognized

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have some models with similar names:

issue-statuse.js
issue-type.js

issue-type is working perfectly, but issue-statuse is causing trouble:

```
WARNING: Encountered "issue_statuses" in payload, but no model was found for model name "issue-status" (resolved model name using soporte@serializer:issue-statuse:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("issue_statuses"))

//<!--app/adapters/application.js-->
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     namespace: 'api/v1',
     host: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
coalesceFindRequests: true,
     headers: {
     withCredentials: true,
     Authorization: 'Basic eG9qbzpzZWNyZXQ=',
     crossDomain: true
     },
     pathForType: function(type) {
       return Ember.String.underscore(type)+'s';
     }

});

// added a 's' for pluralize names, as when we need in underscore are in singular once again ...

//<!--app/models/issue-statuse.js-->
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  short: DS.attr('string'),
  plural: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

I have a workaround in a Serializer, I don't like it but with it it's working fine:

```
//<<!--app/serializers/issue-statuse.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  modelNameFromPayloadKey: function(payloadKey) {
    if (payloadKey === 'issue_statuses') {
      return this._super("issue-statuse"); //this._super(payloadKey.replace('blog/', ''));
    } else {
     return this._super('issue-statuse'); //this._super(payloadKey);
    }
  }
});
```

But if I use this Serializer, I've got a Deprecation Warning:

```
Your custom serializer uses the old version of the Serializer API, with `extract` hooks. Please upgrade your serializers to the new Serializer API using `normalizeResponse` hooks instead.
```

So, I have two options, first one is try to solve why Ember is not finding my model, and the second, use the serializer and try to understand the deprecation and how to eliminate it.

I would prefer option one :-)

Thanks,

### edit

It was a typo here in the name of the model file, it's singular:

```
 //<!--app/models/issue-statuse.js-->
```

### edit 2

I've removed completely the app/serializers/issue-statuse.js and created an initializer with the inflector:

```
//<!--/app/initializers/inflector.js-->
import Ember from 'ember';
export function initialize(/* container, application */) {
  var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
  inflector.uncountable('aamc-pcrs');

  inflector.irregular('issue-statuse', 'issue-statuses');      

}

export default {
  name: 'inflector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

### edit 3

I'm using the

```
     pathForType: function(type) {
   return Ember.String.underscore(type)+'s';
 },
```

in the Adaptor for changing - for _
My Backend API wants issue_statuses instead of issue-statuses for example. Maybe I can just rename the table in the inflector and remove also this line ...

Comment: it's only a guess, but: shouldn't model-names be singular? In your case (sounds weird now....) I guess ember is expecting a model called `issue-statuse` (just without the `s`). And wasn't there a better hook to define pluralisations but the serializer?

Comment: edit: the error actualy says, that ember is looking for an `issue-status` model. (and not `issue-statuses` as you have the model now)

Comment: But if the model is issue-statuse (it's a legacy app), why it's looking for issue-status instead of issue-statuse ? I've found a better way, the inflector.js place to rename the model, still asking why ember misses the correct name... thanks